# XML Parsing/division issue

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I am messing about with the below code, and I can not seem to get this to work correctly... from what I gather all of the code is working perfectly fine, bar the division $distance1 variable.

```
<?php
$start = 'EC1V 0ES';
$end = 'EC4R 3TN';

$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.$start.'&destination='.$end.'&sensor=false';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 
$distance = $xml->route->leg->distance->text;
$distance1 = $distance/1.609; // divided by 1.609 to convert KM into Miles

echo $distance;
echo '<br />';
echo $distance1;

?>
```

Does any one have any ideas what so ever as to what could be causing this? I have tested online and taken a look into the GoogleApis URL (http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=ec1v+0es&destination=ec4r+3tn&sensor=false) and it seems as if my code is pulling the correct values, it just isn't dividing or something... ahh I am confused and a bit of a noob so go nicely please :)

Comment: I get this output when running that script: "4.4 km<br />2.486016159105"

Comment: yeah the output should be "4.4 km<br />2.73403325"

Comment: it's not dividing correctly :/

Comment: @Timothy What means *not correctly* ?

Comment: @hek2mgl: 4.4 / 1.609 != 2.486016159105. I didn't notice first either.. ^^

Comment: Ans what's your current output looking like?

Comment: Does $distance really contains "4.4 km"? So you should remove the "km" before you try to divide it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should cast $distance as float

```
$start = 'EC1V 0ES';
$end = 'EC4R 3TN';

$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.$start.'&destination='.$end.'&sensor=false';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 
$distance = (float) $xml->route->leg->distance->text;
$distance1 = $distance/1.609; // divided by 1.609 to convert KM into Miles

echo $distance;
echo '<br />';
echo $distance1;

// 4.4<br />2.7346177750155
```

Comment: I that works enough! it prints 2.7346177750155 instead of the true value: 2.73403325, but it wont matter too much when I round it to a couple of decimal places :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$start = 'EC1V 0ES';
$end = 'EC4R 3TN';

$url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin='.$start.'&destination='.$end.'&sensor=false';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url); 
$distance = (float) $xml->route->leg->distance->text;
$distance1 = round($distance/1.609,2); // divided by 1.609 to convert KM into Miles

echo $distance;
echo '<br />';
echo $distance1;

?>
```

Updated code is here :) Thanks for all of your help! The above seems to be working fine now :)